# Is there a way to print my e-mails in a book?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there someone who knows if there's something available online where I can print parts of my e-mail inbox?

I've been trying to make the selection by hand, but I just don't have the time to make a final selection. There's always new e-mails coming in, and it's just a lot of work.

Does anybody know a website where I can do this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Memeoirs](http://www.memeoirs.com) does exactly what you need.

You can choose to print the e-mails you have exchanged with your girlfriend only. Furthermore, you can also limit the time period of the conversations, to, say, February 2010 - February 2011. All the hard work is done for you, and that includes stripping away forward / reply quotes, signatures, etc.

The final result is a nice looking book that will be delivered to you, via post.

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of Memeoirs.

Comment: Brilliant. Just made me a book of 238 pages. Amazing to see how many pages we wrote. I didn't think there would be this many pages. Though Valentine's day is already tomorrow (so I will not get the book on time), I couldn't resist and already made a book. I guess sometimes one can still give a spontaneous gift. Thanks a million, really what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a service that exists that operates the way you are thinking.

Depending on your email set up, you can probably mark a bunch with a special marker to cordon them off into a separate area, and just print them all at your leisure. However, you will probably be running into a lot of difficulties with the replies and quoted text.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I use gmail so I can put the e-mails I want to print in a folder, indeed. But as you say, the difficulties arise when dealing with replies and quoted text. That's indeed the hardest part. I was thinking of making a book for my girlfriend out of the e-mails we've exchanged (Valentine's day coming up, you know...). I've tried copy/pasting and creating a PDF myself, but it just doesn't look "print worthy".